# CSS to rotate and position elements in corners of another element

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Right now I have an arrangement like following:

[image]

I want those trees to fit at the upper corners of the squares (each tree at diagonal vertices, like forming an outer square)

**My HTML:**

```
  <div class="outer-wrapper">

    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <div class="box {{box.color}}" ng-repeat="box in boxes" ng-class="{'lit': box.isLit}" ng-click="boxClick(box.id)">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="image" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-if="showImages" ng-click="boxClick(image.id)">
      <img src="{{image.path}}">
    </div>

  </div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.image img{

    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    float: right;   
}

.inner-wrapper {  
  width: 200px;
}

.outer-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

.box {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;    
}
```

How can I achieve this? If I am not using divs in a proper way, or if they can be used in more efficient way to achieve the same thing, it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  give the boxes relative position.And put the div containing the image inside it and give them absolute position.So then you can position the images relative to the boxes.

If you want an image to each corner you should add a div for each corner.Then you could apply different css rules to each of them using `nth-child()`.

If you want to rotate the images just use `transform:rotate();`

Something like this would work for you:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
          <div class="box " >
           <div class="image" >
           <img src="your_image.jpg">
           <img src="your_image.jpg">
           <img src="your_image.jpg">
           <img src="your_image.jpg">
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
  position:relative;
}   

.image{
position:absolute;
}

.image:nth-child(1) {
  top:-15px;
  left:-5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.box .image:nth-child(2) {
  top:-15px;
  right:-5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.box .image:nth-child(3) {
  bottom:-15px;
  left:-5px;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.box .image:nth-child(4){
  bottom:-15px;
  right:-5px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/e06mjvpf/7/

Comment: With absolute position of image I am able to see only one tree

Comment: of course ...if you want more trees just add more divs inside it and if you want each one to each corner just give each a class eg ".top-left{top:0,left:0;}".

Comment: Okay I get it what you said now. Thanks for the fiddle. Actually in my HTML I am using `ng-repeat` of angularjs, so inside it having multiple divs with different classes is a bit tricky..

Comment: I updated my answer so you can do it without different classes

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!